# why expression with 'undefined' does not return boolean

Tags: javascript

My questions might be silly, but why in the expression

```
var query;
var n =  query && query.length > 0;
```

n is 'undefined' and not false? I expected the expression to be evaluates as a boolean. 
It made me curious.

Comment: Logical operators (AND and OR) return the value that determines the outcome of the evaluation. That's just how it is. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators): *"Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values; when they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the `&&` and `||` operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value."*

Comment: I suppose anything done with undefined is undefined. i.e. you are doing '&&' with undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` evaluates its left operand. If that left operand is falsy, it **evaluates to its left operand**. Otherwise, it evaluates to its right operand.

Since JavaScript doesn’t generally have strong typing, this works in the same way as a boolean result for the most part, and allows for convenient tricks, like this one, with `||`:

```
var requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function (callback) { setTimeout(callback, 16); };
```

[Here’s where it’s specified.](https://es5.github.io/#x11.11)

> The production *LogicalANDExpression* : *LogicalANDExpression* &&
>   *BitwiseORExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LogicalANDExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. If ToBoolean(*lval*) is **false**, return *lval*.
> 4. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *BitwiseORExpression*.
> 5. Return GetValue(*rref*).

See also the note at the bottom of the section, which directly addresses your question!

> **NOTE**  The value produced by a `&&` or `||` operator is not necessarily of type Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two operand expressions.